# Why have navbar-default and navbar-inverse for any theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So obviously, one can change the looks by adding one or the other to the `.navbar` element. So it's one very simple way, of choosing between two "themes".

But there are hundreds of themes out on the internet, eg Bootswatch, and each of these themes all come with both `.navbar-default` and `.navbar-inverse` looks.

1. Is it "wrong" or in conflict with the intended use, to not use any of these, and only have the `.navbar` class?
2. Why do all themes come with these two variants of navbar?
3. If I want to make my own look, should I create a third one, eg `.navbar-darkred`, or should I just override .navbar-default? I know I can do both, but is there any reason to make my own, or any reason not to go this way?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your questions...

1. No more so than using a button with only the `.btn` class and not
   `.btn-default`
2. In case, well, you want to have more than one look for a navbar. Say
   for example a double navbar, like this site--a stack exchange navbar and stack overflow navbar, or maybe an inverse navbar footer...
3. I would suggest overriding `.navbar-default` or `.navbar-inverse`,
   in case you want to drop in a different theme at some point (witohut
   having to redefine your custom navbar).

HTH